# How do I fix html parser error on ios 9?

Tags: html, ios, ios9

I have the following code:

```
NSString *pTitle = @"<p>​​បារាំង​ឈ្នះ​កុង​​ត្រា​​​សង់​នាវា​មុជ​ទឹក​​ឲ្យ​​អូស្ត្រាលី​</p>";
HTMLParser *parserTitle = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithString:pTitle error: &tError];
    if (tError) {
        [title setText:@""];
    }
    else{
        HTMLNode *tBodyNode = [parserTitle body];
        [title setText:[tBodyNode allContents]];
        NSLog(@"title%@",[tBodyNode allContents]);
    }
```

When I run on simulator 9.3 output result is:

áááá»áá áá»áââáá¶áá¶ááâááááâáá»áââáááá¶âââáááâáá¶áá¶âáá»áâáá¹áââá²áá

But when i run on simulator 8 it work well. Does anyone know why? I use zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `tError` set? If so, log it. Update your question with its output.

Comment: tError is not true. it alway go to else